# AWS EC2 Image Builder "No Space Left" while Building Image

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk, amazon-ami

I am using AWS Image Builder Pipeline to deploy EC2 AMIs. However while my AMI is building I get the following errors from the Build Instance EC2 (created by Image Builder) that should spin up the AMI:

> Stderr:
>
> tar:
> splunk-soar/usr/python39/lib64/python3.9/config-3.9-x86_64-linux-gnu/makesetup:
> Cannot open: No space left on device
>
> tar:
> splunk-soar/usr/python39/lib64/python3.9/config-3.9-x86_64-linux-gnu/python-config.py:
> Cannot open: No space left on device
>
> TOE has completed execution with failure - write
> /var/lib/amazon/toe/TOE_2023-07-31_13-33-45_UTC-0_dfb87270-2fa6-11ee-a43c-0af2ba430d71/detailedoutput.json: no space left on device.

I suspect that the issue is how I’m attaching my EBS volume in **return_my_component_doc()** below.

Here is my image recipe:

```py
    my_image_version = "1.0.9" 
    
    my_component = imagebuilder.CfnComponent(self, "myComponent",
        name="My-Image-Component",
        platform="Linux",
        version=my_image_version,  # ie: "1.0.3",
        description="Downloads, installs and configures on Amazon Linux",
        supported_os_versions=["Amazon Linux 2"],
        data= return_my_component_doc():
    )
    
    my_image_recipe = imagebuilder.CfnImageRecipe(self, ",myImageRecipe",
        components=[{"componentArn": my_component.attr_arn}],
        name="My-Image-Recipe",
        # Amazon Linux2 X86 64bit Kernel 5.10
        parent_image="ami-076bca9dd71a9a5670",
        version=my_image_version,  # ie: "1.0.3",
        working_directory="/tmp",
    
        # EBS Volume that I want to use for spinning up the AMI.
        block_device_mappings=[imagebuilder.CfnImageRecipe.InstanceBlockDeviceMappingProperty(
                device_name="/dev/sde",
                ebs=imagebuilder.CfnImageRecipe.EbsInstanceBlockDeviceSpecificationProperty(
                delete_on_termination=False,
                encrypted=False,
                iops=3000,
                throughput=125,
                volume_size=50,
                volume_type="gp3"
            )
        )]
    )
    
    my_image_pipeline = imagebuilder.CfnImagePipeline(self, "MyImagePipeline",
        infrastructure_configuration_arn=my_infrastructure_configuration.attr_arn,
        distribution_configuration_arn=my_distribution_configuration.attr_arn,
        name="My AMI Deployment Pipeline",
        image_recipe_arn = my_image_recipe.attr_arn,
    )
```

And here is the data for my custom component to attach the EBS.

```py
        def return_my_component_doc():
            my_component_doc = f'''
            name: MyDeploymentDocument_A
            description: This is document for downloading, installing and deploying.
            schemaVersion: 1.0
            phases:
              - name: build
                steps:
                  - name: MountVolume
                    action: ExecuteBash
                    inputs:
                      commands:
                        - sudo mkfs -t xfs /dev/sde
                        - sudo mkdir /data
                        - sudo mount /dev/sde /data
            ‘’’  
            return my_component_doc
```

Screenshots showing disk usage from inside the ImageBuilder provisioned EC2 that creates the AMI. It shows that the 50GB EBS volume is not being used by ImageBuilder.
[image]

[image]

When I ssh inside the Build Instance EC2 that should spin up the AMI it looks like it’s only writing to the default 8GB EBS volume and not the 50GB EBS volume that I created and attached above. I would like to use the larger EBS volumes for spinning up the AMI.

How can I resolve this error? I want my EC2 Image Builder Pipeline to use a larger block store when creating the AMI.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you mounted the additional volume to `/data` but *no space left on device* happens below `/var`.

Depending on the parent image that you are using, you can increase the root volume as well. To do so use the same device name (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/device_naming.html) and override it with a larger size than 8.